# Trying to filter list in Python (flask) and assign to session variable... TypeError

Tags: python, flask, filter, session-variables

```
TypeError: Object of type 'filter' is not JSON serializable
```

This is really confusing me. ( My 'realfiles' function is just making sure the directory list doesn't contain any Thumbs.db or .DS_Store files, and even if I reduce it down to "return True" I get the same error. )

I'm not trying to serialize a filter, whatever that even means. I'm serializing a list that is that filter's output. Right? Python is not my best language, so I initially thought my mistake was trying to assign the output of the filter to the session variable in the same line- something that would have worked fine in Javascript-

```
session['dir_listed_projects'] = filter( realfiles , pList )
session['dir_listed_templates'] = filter( realfiles , tList )
```

so I rewrote it to assign to an intermediate variable:

```
@app.route('/projects', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def projects():
    listA = listdir( outta( here, 2 ) + '/Projects')
    listB = listdir( outta( here, 2 ) + '/_Templates')
    pList = filter( realfiles , listA )
    tList = filter( realfiles , listB )
    session['dir_listed_projects'] = pList
    session['dir_listed_templates'] = tList
    return render_template( 'projects.html' )
```

nope.

```
TypeError: Object of type 'filter' is not JSON serializable
```

If I don't use a filter at all but assign the listdir's output directly, the page will render with no error- and it was working fine *with* the filter before I started upgrading from Python 2.x to 3.x.

Comment: In python3 filter does not return a list but a filter object. Convert that to a list bevore storing it in the session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3, `filter` returns a filter object (an iterator), not a list.

```
filter(lambda x: x == 2, [1, 2, 3])
<filter object at 0x7f37049af210>
```

To get the output as a list, use the `list` function.

```
list(filter(lambda x: x == 2, [1, 2, 3]))
[2]
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would I ever want the filter object instead of the filtered list?

Comment: Sorry, let me try that comment again:

The filter object is like a generator so is much more efficient if you want to iterate over it later. See for example the difference between range and xrange in python2.